# Linq 2 SQL Sum using lambda and handling nulls

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

When using sum with lambda in Linq to SQL using the following code:

```
int query = (from f in odc.RDetails
                     where f.ticketID == int.Parse(ticket.ToString())
                     select f).Sum(x => x.Rate);
```

I get the following error:

**The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

. You have to make sure `x.Rate` is an `int`, and not an `int?` (an `int` that accepts `null` as a value).

. If the query has no elements, `.Sum` won't do anything and will return `null`. Choose a default value, let's say `0`.

```
var query = from f in odc.RDetails
            where f.ticketID == int.Parse(ticket.ToString())
            select f;

int result = query.Any() 
             ? query.Sum(x => x.Rate ?? 0) // use the ?? if x.Rate is an "int?".
             : 0; // default value you can choose.
```

Comment: I'm getting operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type int and int

Comment: The `.Sum` can be called also after testing for nullity in the query. New edit...

Comment: TryParse wants two parameters!

Comment: This doesn't compile... with the tryparse.  Also ticket is not null...there is no need to check for null within ticket..

Comment: If ticket is not the problem, I'll remove the "defense" against it. Edited.

Comment: Still getting operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type int and int on x.rate

Comment: So remove it - you just have to use the `??` if `Rate` is an `int?`. Use the `query.Sum(x => x.Rate)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would break the `int.Parse(ticket.ToString())` onto its own line to isolate that parse from the Linq for debugging.

We don't know whether that is throwing the exception or if one of the `RDetails.Rate` values is null.  Is it indeed a `Nullable<int>`?

If `RDetails.Rate` is a `Nullable<int>`, then you could `...Sum(x => x.Rate ?? 0)` and avoid the exception.